# Controlling audio player when click on image buttons using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have started to create my audio player and would like to control it using images (a play and a stop image).
what i have so far:

**audio.html**

```
<div id="audioPlayer">
    <audio id="mediPlay" preload="none" controls="controls">
        <source src="audio/Crystaligned Dream (Short Version).mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <img class="mediaButton" id="playBtn" src="audio/img/play.png" alt="play"/>
    <img class="mediaButton" id="stopBtn" src="audio/img/stop.png" alt="stop" />
</div>
```

**controls.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#playBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('player').play();
  }, false); 
  $('#stopBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('player').stop();
  }, false);
});
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM player hasn't `.stop()` function. You should use `.pouse()` instead. Also the [`.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) and [`.pause()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause) functions do work on audio/video element.

```
$('#playBtn').on('click', function () {
  $('audio')[0].play();
});
$('#stopBtn').on('click', function () {
  $('audio')[0].pause();
});
```

```js
$('#playBtn').on('click', function () {
  $('audio')[0].play();
});
$('#stopBtn').on('click', function () {
  $('audio')[0].pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="audioPlayer">
  <audio id="mediPlay" preload="none" controls="controls">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <img class="mediaButton" id="playBtn" src="audio/img/play.png" alt="play"/>&nbsp;<img class="mediaButton" id="stopBtn" src="audio/img/stop.png" alt="stop" />
</div>
```

---

If you want to replay audio, use this code

```
$('audio')[0].currentTime = 0;
$('audio')[0].play();
```

```js
$('#playBtn').on('click', function () {
  $('audio')[0].play();
});
$('#stopBtn').on('click', function () {
  $('audio')[0].pause();
});
$('#repBtn').on('click', function () {
  $('audio')[0].currentTime = 0;
  $('audio')[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="audioPlayer">
  <audio id="mediPlay" preload="none" controls="controls">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <img class="mediaButton" id="playBtn" src="audio/img/play.png" alt="play"/>
  <img class="mediaButton" id="stopBtn" src="audio/img/stop.png" alt="stop" />
  <img id="repBtn" src="audio/img/stop.png" alt="replay" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ! works well, if i was to incorporate 'stop' functionality however? (rather than pausing the current position), is there a function to return the source file being played to the beginning?